# Deploy Act Framework to production in linux server running weblogic server

Tags: java, serverless, actframework

I created an Act.Framework scheduler application (java) that process csv files from ftp server. Everything works well in my local environment on Windows 10. How do I deploy the application to the Dev and Test environments running on Linux servers and have existing applications on weblogic application servers?

I've come accross this doc: http://actframework.org/doc/reference/configuration.md but it doesn't give guidelines or steps on how to do this

Answer (score 2):

ActFramework is a non-servlet Web application framework. It doesn't deploy to any Servet applicaiton servers, including Tomcat, Jetty and WebLogic.

To deploy your actframework application, do:

```
mvn clean package
```

And then

```
scp target/dist/*.gz $username@$remoteHost:
```

Then you can ssh into your remote host and do

```
tar xzf *.gz
```

Finally you need to run the app by

```
cd $proj
./start
```

Normally you should also setup your front-end http server, e.g. nginx to proxy the request to your application

**Update**

With regarding to set up frontend HTTP server, here is an example of nginx configuration file:

```
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     api-sit.mb.thinking.studio;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name api.myapp.com;
  client_max_body_size 11m;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass        http://localhost:5460;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    add_header X-App-Version $upstream_http_server;
  }


}
```

The above configuration made assumption that:

1. Your domain name is `api.myapp.com`
2. Your act app is listening to port `5460`
3. You have SSL certificate setup and installed in 
   `/etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/` dir

Comment: Could you please provide a detailed explainantion on "setup your front-end http server" please